# Failure to take a call for step in Pokemon

Tags: pokemon

If a mistake is made in a Pokemon game, and neither player catches it, does the player who failed to do the correct action lose the game, or is the game a draw, or do you continue to play the game since the mistake was overlook. Example: A coin was suppose to be toss and if tails the Pokemon could not attack. I failed to (overlook) the toss, several turns later I realize my mistake. This mistake may have put me ahead in the game (if the toss had been tails.) I forfeited the game and later try to look up an official rule on this to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

It depends whether you are playing casually or in an official tournament. For tournaments, it also depends on its type - beginner-friendly *Tier 1* tournaments like League Challenges are different to *Tier 2* tournaments where players are expected to abide by the rules all the time.

1. In casual play, both players have to agree on the resolution of the game state, i.e.

   - ignore the mistake
   - try to rewind the game state to the point before the mistake
   - the opposing player draws a Prize card (or more of them)
   - player who made the mistake loses
2. In tournaments, everything depends on the official *judge* (or more of them) - they are the only ones who can rule the resolution of the game state. In addition to possible resolutions above, they can also give a Caution or a Warning to one or both players.

   The main document for judges is **Pokémon TCG Penalty Guidelines**, available from [Rules & Resources](https://www.pokemon.com/us/play-pokemon/about/tournaments-rules-and-resources/) page of official website.

> A coin was suppose to be toss and if tails the Pokemon could not attack. I failed to (overlook) the toss, several turns later I realize my mistake.

Using *Penalty Guidelines* from October 2019, the actual resolution depends on "rewindability" and overall damage of the game state. Because several turns have passed, the problem would probably fall into *8.1.2. Gameplay Error - Major*, but might also be closer to *8.1.3. Gameplay Error - Severe*.

Both players are responsible for maintaining the game state. If the game state is irreversibly broken, the opponent might get a penalty for *8.1. Gameplay Error* as well.

The actual penalties strongly depend on the particular situation.

Comment: This is (now, anyway) very slightly incorrect - you do not "draw prize card(s) for free", you just don't have to take those prizes anymore - but otherwise a good answer.  It could be improved by linking to the penalty guidelines linked on [this page](https://www.pokemon.com/us/play-pokemon/about/tournaments-rules-and-resources/), though the specific guideline link now is a dated link which raises the possibility it will stale quickly sadly.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Play! Pokemon Penalty Guidelines](https://assets.pokemon.com//assets/cms2/pdf/play-pokemon/rules/play-pokemon-tcg-penalty-guidelines-10232019-en.pdf) it depends on the severity of the mistake made, and the Tier in which you are playing. It can range from a Caution all the way up to a Game Loss.

For you example it would probably be a Game-Play Error - Major for "Using an Ability when a card prevents its use". For this error in a Tier 1 match you would get a Warning, in a Tier 2 your opponent has to take two fewer prize cards. In either case your opponent would get a Caution for failing to maintain game state.